# Spyder does not run Python scripts after matplotlib upgrade

Tags: python, matplotlib, ide, upgrade, spyder

I was coding in Python 2.7 with **Spyder 2.1.9**, using **matplotlib 1.1**. The operating system is Linux Ubuntu 12.04 LTS.

I requested the upgrade of matplotlib with `sudo pip --upgrade python-matplotlib`. The upgrade went well: the end message is `successfully installed matplotlib numpy foos bars`.

Now, if I open an interpreter in the terminal and type

```
  import matplotlib
  print(matplotlib.__version__)
```

the answer is **1.5.1**. This version of matplotlib is installed in `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/__init__.pyc`, if this piece of information can be useful.

However, when I come back to the Spyder IDE and I try to run any of the scripts that were dwelling there (key F5), nothing happens any longer. No interpreter window gets active within Spyder. Ditto if I create a brand new 'hallo world' script.

The internal console in Spyder does work, it's just the *scripts* that are not executed, whether new or old. This is a snapshot of Spyder internal console in the new setting:

[image: Spyder internal console sees the new version of matplotlib]

What is the possible cause of this?
How do I get Spyder working again as usual?

Comment: I confess I'm a bit uncomfortable in troubleshooting Spyder 2.1.9 from 2012. Any reason why you don't upgrade to the last version?

Comment: @Roberto I have an interest in keeping this machine going on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS and spyder 2.1.9 is the version shipped with it. I checked that Ubuntu 14.04 LTS actually ships spyder 2.2.5. If possible I would leave the status quo unchanged though.

Comment: @VadimShkaberda Thanks. We are getting there. I downgraded matplotlib to the earlier stable version with `sudo pip matplotlib=1.4.3` and spyder 2.1.9 worked again. As a new side effect, the interpreter-in-spyder issues a number of warnings, but I will post another question on this. The core functionalities appear to work again. If you convert the comment into an answer I am happy to mark it as effective.

Comment: And why don't you want to upgrade your Spyder?

Comment: @VadimShkaberda I want to keep Ubuntu 12.04 LTS. The possible issues with upgrading spyder are set in [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/769233). The issues from downgrading matplotlib are shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37097838). The latter is already half-effective and seems less time demanding for me to fix. I am open to the spyder upgrade if I gain enough elements to believe that it is a relatively straightforward, well-documented process.

Comment: @XavierStuvw well... do what you want, but in my opinion either you freeze the system, or don't... Your choices of updating matplotlib but keeping Spyder at an older version are conflicting; either you spend a lot of time trying to patch this conflict, or maybe just upgrade Spyder. Did you find written somewhere that a newer version of Spyder wouldn't be compatible with Ubuntu 12?

Comment: @Roberto The possible issues with upgrading spyder are set in this [post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/769233).  I am open to the spyder upgrade if I gain enough elements to believe that it is a relatively straightforward, well-documented process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were many [bugs](https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/issues/2793) when using matplotlib 1.5 on Spyder versions up to 2.3.7. I guess you should downgrade matplotlib.

Comment: For the interested readers. Downgrading matplotlib to 1.4.3 does restore the functionalities of spyder 2.1.9 but produces warnings that are being discussed in this other [Stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37097838/)