# Downgrading matplotlib throws bad key errors in spyder IDE

Tags: python, matplotlib, spyder, downgrade

I am running Python 2.7.3 on a Ubuntu 12.04 LTS distribution. I use spyder 2.9.1 as IDE.

As detailed in another [Stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37089403/spyder-does-not-run-python-scripts-after-matplotlib-upgrade) of mine, I upgraded matplotlib from **1.1** to **1.5.1** only to find that there are acknowledged clashes between the IDE and matplotlib 1.5.1. I then downgraded matlplotlib from **1.5.1** to **1.4.3**, the previously stable version.

I gained back the core functionalities of spyder that went lost with the upgrade. However, now the console throws the following warnings:

```
Python 2.7.3 (default, Jun 22 2015, 19:33:41) 
[GCC 4.6.3] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

Bad key "axes.prop_cycle" on line 2 in
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/mpl-data/stylelib/seaborn-colorblind.mplstyle.
You probably need to get an updated matplotlibrc file from
http://matplotlib.sf.net/_static/matplotlibrc or from the matplotlib source distribution

<tens of these bad key notifications with the same suggestion>

Imported NumPy 1.11.0, SciPy 0.9.0, Matplotlib 1.4.3
Type "scientific" for more details.
>>>
```

The file on http://matplotlib.sf.net/_static/matplotlibrc is easily accessible. I have seen that this file is already present in my computer in 5 locations:

```
me@computer:~$ locate matplotlibrc
/etc/matplotlibrc
/home/me/Downloads/programs/ParaView-4.3.1-Linux-64bit/lib/paraview-4.3/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/mpl-data/matplotlibrc
/opt/paraview/ParaView-4.1.0-Linux-64bit/lib/paraview-4.1/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/mpl-data/matplotlibrc
/opt/paraview/ParaView-4.3.1-Linux-64bit/lib/paraview-4.3/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/mpl-data/matplotlibrc
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/matplotlib/mpl-data/matplotlibrc
```

The questions are:

- Is copying and pasting `matplotlibrc` all that I should do? (Strange that `pip` didn't bother about that...)
- If so, should I update all of just some of those 5 occurrences? (The fact that another program, Paraview, uses it seems to complicate the matter...)

Thanks for helping me out.

Comment: I can't help a lot. All I can say, that `axes.prop_cycle` was added to matplotlib in version 1.5. And, as you can see [here](http://matplotlib.org/api/api_changes.html#color-cycle-deprecated), you can add this parameter to matplotlibrc manually, but "Having both parameters in the same rc file is not recommended as the result cannot be predicted."

Comment: @VadimShkaberda Thanks. This is interesting, since matplotlib 1.5 should not be there in the first place because the aim is to remove it. I don't cherish the idea of adding 1.5 features after downgrading it. So it looks that there is some 'old' bits from the 'new' version that have not be cleared. I would be glad to follow the suggestion `You probably need to get an updated matplotlibrc file from http://matplotlib.sf.net/_static/matplotlibrc or from the matplotlib source distribution` if I have some guidance on where this file has to be replaced for maximum benefit/minimum damage.

Comment: @ XavierStuvw I guess you should use [Customizing matplotlib](http://matplotlib.org/users/customizing.html#the-matplotlibrc-file) as an instruction.

Comment: @VadimShkaberda Most interesting reading, thanks. This section of Benjamin Root's tutorial [The Anatomy of Python (Youtube, 2013)](https://youtu.be/c553uCRmEVc?t=1h2m21s) discusses the matplotlib customization too.